# React не правильно обновляется State redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

При любом изменении инпута в state записывается и возвращается всегда один символ, который был нажат на клавиатуре последним. Возможно не внимательный либо что-то не так делаю и не могу понять почему так!
Если обновить страницу - символ будет по одному последнему добавляться к предыдущим!
Так же если строку "9" переместить в component2.js - всё будет работать как нужно (Как я понял это наверное из-за неверного получения данных из обновлённого State)

Данные передаются для обработки и вывода value с component.js в component2.js (Указанно в pastebin)

```js
//reducers.js
case UPDATE_ARTICLE_STATE:
    return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value
    };
 
//component.js
const state = useSelector(state => state.createArticle, shallowEqual);
const handleChange = (data) => {
    dispatch(updateArticleState(data));
}
 
const handlePublish = (props) => {
    const content = <PublishContent user={user} link={state.link} handleChange={handleChange} />;
    openModal(content);
}
 
//component2.js
const handleChange = event => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    props.handleChange({name, value});
}
```

```html
<input 
    type="text"
    className="form-control input input-search"
    id="link"
    name="link"
    value={ props.link || '' }
    onChange={handleChange} />
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в виде текста, а не скриншота

Comment: @denisnumb готово!

Comment: @AleksandrSmirnov поставь console.log в этих местах и скажы что выводит
что в action.payload
что в props.link из инпута
что в data перед dispach

твой код не запускается надо доделать чтобы запустить но думаю не потребуется просто глянь где target.value теряется